# linux c++: test of the cacheline size performance effect not as expected

Tags: c, linux, performance, caching, size

It's said that for normal x86 cpu(i7 mac), the cpu cacheline size is 64bytes, so if use an array size<64, it will exist in just one cache line and will be fast, when the cache line size is bigger, program will slow down.

Below is my program:

```
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
size_t cacheline=16;
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    size_t loopCount=2000000000;
    if(argc==2){loopCount=atol(argv[1]);}
    printf("loop=%ld\n",loopCount);
    int array[cacheline];
    for(size_t a=0;a<cacheline;++a){
        array[a]=a;
    }
    size_t c=0;
    long sum=1;
    for(size_t i=0;i<loopCount;++i){
        if(c==cacheline)c=0;
        sum+=array[c++];//
    }
    printf("sum=%ld\n",sum);
    return 0;
}

clang++ test07_cacheline.cpp -O2 -o test07_cacheline && time ./test07_cacheline 2000000000
loop=2000000000
sum=63354543092609

real    0m2.810s
user    0m2.794s
sys 0m0.009s
```

But in my test program I found, no matter I set the size of "array" to be 16, 64, 256 or 65536, time excution time is basically the same. What's wrong with the theory or my program design? I also tried some other programs from internet, same result, as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
long timediff(clock_t t1,clock_t t2){
    return (t2-t1)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    int array_size=65536;
    if(argc>=2)array_size=atoi(argv[1]);
    int repeat_times=2000000000;
    long array[array_size];
    for(int i=0;i<array_size;++i){
        array[i]=i;
    }
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int c=0;
    clock_t start=clock();
    while(j++<repeat_times){
        if(k==array_size){k=0;}
        c+=array[k++];
    }
    clock_t end=clock();
    printf("c=%d,%lu\n",c,timediff(start,end));
    return 0;
}

g++ test08_cacheline.cpp -O2 -o test08_cacheline && ./test08_cacheline
c=1865233920,2800
```

No matter how bit array_size. So any explanations of how cacheline affects performance in my program?

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? Also, how are you measuring time in your first program? I don't see any timekeeping code, and if you measure the program as a whole, your results might be thrown off by your calls to `printf` etc.

Comment: The code you show seems to be in c, but you have tagged this question with c++. Please edit the tags accordingly.

Comment: I changed my tag to c. I compiled with -O2, just my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that both the executions are **exploiting data locality**.

You're reading from a contiguous array. Your cache will read contiguous blocks of your array. The only difference is in the number of times you load blocks.

This number is no so big and, moreover, the compiler has the ability of predict when load a new block especially if you flagged some optimization rules such as vectorization.

For more read [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html)

If you wanna see how performance change try modifying your code in this way:

```
   while(j++<repeat_times){
        if(k==array_size){k=0;}
        int position = ((c+k)*j)%array_size;
        c+=array[position];
        k++;
    }
```

In such a way you will lose data locality.

---

### UPDATE

Performance depends more on memory access pattern than on cache size. More precisely, if the program is mainly sequential, cache size is not a big deal. If there are quite a lot of random access, cache size really matters.

If you want try to see how cache size leads to different performance you can try:

1. Remove data locality doing random accesses
2. Then changing the size of the array.

In this way if the size of the array fits into your cache per each random access the block will already be into the cache.

**N.B.** You're not the only one using the cache on your PC!

Comment: Thanks, I know this "lose data locality" will affect performance, but what I wish to see is to check how cache line size will affect performance, and try to use a pure c program(without gcc extensions) to find out the number of cacheline size(64) by experiment. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tested to set "cacheline" from 16, to 65536, same result. I expect when it's 65536, more "cache invalidate" should happen, and thus be more slow?

Comment: @Troskyvs did you use random access for testing? Can you share your code?